# Animación frame by frame

Tags: android

tengo una animación frame by frame que cuando se oprime el botón comienza y al volver a oprimirlo se detiene.
Ahora quise implementar que se detenga luego de unos segundos utilizando un `CountDownTimer` pero no funciona. 
Que me esta fallando?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private void animate() {
        final ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading);
        imgView.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);
        imgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation_list);

        final AnimationDrawable frame = (AnimationDrawable) imgView.getBackground();
        if (frame.isRunning()) {
            frame.stop();
        } else {
            frame.start();
            new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    frame.stop();
                }
            };
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                animate();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: No para o da error?

Comment: No para, como si no leyera esa parte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que nunca iniciaste el Timer con .start();

Tu código debería quedar

```
new CountDownTimer(3000, 1000) {
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                public void onFinish() {
                    frame.stop();
                }
            }.start();
```